# facebook login sdk throws Application ID cannot be Null

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.1

The facebook SDK throws me an error `Application ID cannot be Null`.

When debugging I noticed the application doesn't retrieve the metadata tag value I added under the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in my project directory under the 'application' tag

metadata tag:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="6xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
```

Comment: have you created your app on facebook ??..test some samples..really easy to use. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads

Comment: where did you put the <metadata> tag?

Comment: this worked for me: 
        <!-- Facebook SDK metadata and activity -->
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />

Comment: I put the Metadata tag directly under the <application> tag

Comment: I forgot to add the <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" /> thanks Mike!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mt bad...
I forgot to add the `<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" />` tag to the manifest file.